# Getting the ALL the value of $i in for loop from the controller in laravel to show in views

Tags: laravel, for-loop

This is my code in Controller
I loop my data in a for loop

```
public function dtrdata(){
    $totalnumdays = 31; //31
    $firstdaynum = 4; //6 max // convert day to num
    $reset = 0;
    $weekdays = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');


    for($i=1;$i<=$totalnumdays;$i++){
        for($x=0; $x<count($weekdays); $x++){
            $index = $firstdaynum+$reset; //fri start; index in array

            if($index == 6){
                $reset = $firstdaynum * -1;
            }else{
                $reset++;
            }
            break;                              
        }
    }
    return view('pages/admin', compact('i'));
}


//Views


    <tr>
        <td>{{ i}}</td>
    </tr>
```

I want to show all the values in my views but im having problem showing all the value instead it only gets the last value

Comment: you don't even have a `$row` variable to pass to the view in the first place.

Comment: when you return view, you only has `$i` value. So, why do you use `$row`?

Comment: okay I get it but when I echo it without $row  and just echo $i it only show the last value, how can i get all of the value and show each in <td> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put value of i into an array, for example

```
public function dtrdata(){
    $totalnumdays = 31; //31
    $firstdaynum = 4; //6 max // convert day to num
    $reset = 0;
    $valueOfI=[];
    $weekdays = array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun');
    for($i=1;$i<=$totalnumdays;$i++){
        for($x=0; $x<count($weekdays); $x++){
            $index = $firstdaynum+$reset; //fri start; index in array
            $valueOfI[] = $i;
            if($index == 6){
                $reset = $firstdaynum * -1;
            }else{
                $reset++;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return view('pages/admin', compact('valueOfI'));
}
```

and in view you can do,
`{{jsond_encode($valueOfI)}}`
or you can convert array to string by using php `implode` method,
https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

`$valueOfI` is array so need to pass as variable check here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_compact.asp